# Create browse path from node ID

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have an OPC-UA client written in C# which uses the `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` service to retrieve the node ID of a given browse path, like `/2:SRV01/2:NodeA`.

Is there a reverse function or how else can I restore the browse path if I'm given a certain NodeId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reverse correlation from `NodeId` to `BrowsePath`.

In fact, there can be any number of `BrowsePath`s that lead to a given `Node`. It all depends on the structure of the address space. Part of what `BrowsePath` does is resolve those ambiguities by specifying exact reference relationships and browse names for each path segment.